# Jersey: can't inject HttpServletRequest, getting hk2 errors

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm trying to get HttpServletRequest injected into my Jersey resource class. I'm getting the error "`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: The class HttpServletRequest has no constructor marked @Inject and no zero argument constructor`". I'm using Java 8.

So far as I can tell, I'm doing a totally plain-vanilla Jersey app. Here's the code, all of it:

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class TestInjection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ResourceConfig app = new ResourceConfig();
        app.register(Foo.class);
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8088/");
        org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server jettyServer = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(uri, app, false);
        jettyServer.start();
    }

    @Path("/hello")
    public static class Foo {

        @GET
        public String go(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

}
```

It chokes on the @Context HttpServletRequest part. If I make the HttpServletRequest a field, it just fails silently and the request is null.

Here are the dependencies. jersey.version is 2.27:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the full stack trace. (The error I reported above I found by stepping through the code, so it's a bit different.)

```
May 29, 2018 2:09:56 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1177)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1260)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:581)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:590)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainer.handle(JettyHttpContainer.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    contracts={javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=157
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=1272665704
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.igdCacheCompute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$400(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1180)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1177)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1260)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:581)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getInjecteeDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:590)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.lambda$new$0(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.lambda$new$0(Cache.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:249)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Cache.apply(Cache.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainer.handle(JettyHttpContainer.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried to annotate Foo with @Singleton ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jersey-container-jetty-http` only run an standard HTTP server. If you want to use `HttpServletRequest`, then you need a Servlet container. For that, you need to use `jersey-container-jetty-servlet`, and instead of using `JettyHttpContainerFactory` to create the server, you need to use [`JettyWebContainerFactory`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jetty-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jetty/servlet/JettyWebContainerFactory.java).

Comment: Thanks, Paul, outstanding. Would never have found it otherwise.